# wifi adapter does not work in older kernel

Tags: drivers, 22.04

Our company forces us to downgrade to specific kernel, because of product requirements of Digital Guardian said so(axiom, cannot be changed). In my case it's from 6.2.0-32-generic down to 5.19.0-45-generic. Using older kernel my wifi module on Lenovo P53 (anyhow it's ubuntu certified) does not work. Can someone recommend a way, how to find out what is missing (while booted in "working" kernel) and how to make it work in older one as well?

note: if I reboot again to newer kernel, everything works again.

UPDATE:

```
lspci -nnk -d ::0280
52:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:0080]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

UPDATE2: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` as ran in newer kernel, where wifi works. Returns nothing in older kernel.

```
[   12.763037] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   12.781561] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[   12.781576] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[   12.781998] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: loaded firmware version 72.daa05125.0 cc-a0-72.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[   12.953490] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
[   12.954059] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[   13.106123] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Detected RF HR B3, rfid=0x10a100
[   13.175678] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: base HW address: 94:e6:f7:f3:ef:e9
[   13.193880] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0 wlp82s0: renamed from wlan0
[  330.316983] Modules linked in: rfcomm xt_conntrack nft_chain_nat xt_MASQUERADE nf_nat nf_conntrack_netlink nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype nft_compat nf_tables libcrc32c nfnetlink br_netfilter bridge stp llc ccm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep overlay snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation binfmt_misc soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_sof_utils snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_ctl_led soundwire_bus snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_tcc_cooling snd_hda_intel x86_pkg_temp_thermal iwlmvm snd_intel_dspcfg intel_powerclamp snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_seq_midi mei_hdcp mei_pxp snd_hda_codec coretemp intel_rapl_msr tps6598x nls_iso8859_1 snd_seq_midi_event mac80211 kvm_intel btusb snd_hda_core snd_rawmidi snd_hwdep
[  330.317033]  libarc4 btrtl kvm uvcvideo snd_pcm cmdlinepart processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy iwlwifi irqbypass snd_seq btbcm spi_nor videobuf2_vmalloc processor_thermal_device think_lmi rapl btintel snd_seq_device intel_cstate thinkpad_acpi videobuf2_memops processor_thermal_rfim serio_raw typec_displayport firmware_attributes_class intel_wmi_thunderbolt btmtk wmi_bmof mtd nvram elan_i2c ee1004 8250_dw snd_timer videobuf2_v4l2 processor_thermal_mbox cfg80211 bluetooth videodev processor_thermal_rapl input_leds snd mei_me intel_rapl_common videobuf2_common cdc_mbim ecdh_generic joydev cdc_wdm mc mei ecc soundcore intel_soc_dts_iosf intel_pch_thermal serial_multi_instantiate ledtrig_audio platform_profile int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone nvidia_uvm(POE) mac_hid int3400_thermal acpi_pad acpi_thermal_rel sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport ramoops reed_solomon pstore_blk pstore_zone efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 dm_crypt hid_microsoft ff_memless hid_generic cdc_ncm
[ 4942.434971] Modules linked in: xt_nat xt_tcpudp veth rfcomm xt_conntrack nft_chain_nat xt_MASQUERADE nf_nat nf_conntrack_netlink nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype nft_compat nf_tables libcrc32c nfnetlink br_netfilter bridge stp llc ccm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep overlay snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation binfmt_misc soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_sof_utils snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_ctl_led soundwire_bus snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_tcc_cooling snd_hda_intel x86_pkg_temp_thermal iwlmvm snd_intel_dspcfg intel_powerclamp snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_seq_midi mei_hdcp mei_pxp snd_hda_codec coretemp intel_rapl_msr tps6598x nls_iso8859_1 snd_seq_midi_event mac80211 kvm_intel btusb snd_hda_core
[ 4942.435032]  snd_rawmidi snd_hwdep libarc4 btrtl kvm uvcvideo snd_pcm cmdlinepart processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy iwlwifi irqbypass snd_seq btbcm spi_nor videobuf2_vmalloc processor_thermal_device think_lmi rapl btintel snd_seq_device intel_cstate thinkpad_acpi videobuf2_memops processor_thermal_rfim serio_raw typec_displayport firmware_attributes_class intel_wmi_thunderbolt btmtk wmi_bmof mtd nvram elan_i2c ee1004 8250_dw snd_timer videobuf2_v4l2 processor_thermal_mbox cfg80211 bluetooth videodev processor_thermal_rapl input_leds snd mei_me intel_rapl_common videobuf2_common cdc_mbim ecdh_generic joydev cdc_wdm mc mei ecc soundcore intel_soc_dts_iosf intel_pch_thermal serial_multi_instantiate ledtrig_audio platform_profile int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone nvidia_uvm(POE) mac_hid int3400_thermal acpi_pad acpi_thermal_rel sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport ramoops reed_solomon pstore_blk pstore_zone efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 dm_crypt hid_microsoft ff_memless
```

UPDATE3:

lscpi shows this wifi device:

```
52:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:0080]
```

cannot modprobe iwlwifi  (and nothing in dmesg contrary to 'see dmesg' hint)

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:838 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='iwlwifi'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

and iwlwifi cannot be installed:

```
sudo apt install firmware-iwlwifi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package firmware-iwlwifi
```

some other commands:

```
modinfo iwlwifi
modinfo: ERROR: Module iwlwifi not found.
sudo dpkg -l | grep iwl
<nothing>
lsmod | grep iwl
<nothing>
```

UPDATE4:

grep -ir iwl /etc/modprobe.d

```
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:remove iwlwifi \
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
```

dkms status

```
backport-iwlwifi/9858, 5.19.0-45-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
backport-iwlwifi/9858, 6.2.0-32-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
nvidia/535.86.05, 5.19.0-45-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia/535.86.05, 6.2.0-31-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia/535.86.05, 6.2.0-32-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: Probably no. You could theoretically backport the driver, but it sounds like a lot of work for absolutely no reason - and your company should probably learn to keep systems patched.

Comment: sure. The problems goes transitively from DigitalGuardian company which security product requires turned of secureboot and their builds target specific and quite old kernels. Our executives were impressed by that probably, so they bought it. Now we have to live with it.

Comment: Add the output of `lspci -nnk -d ::0280` terminal command

Comment: question updated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Append `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: dmesg in 'working kernel' shows iwlwifi. No such line in 'not working kernel'

Comment: @waltinator sadly no. Given script just shows, that I really need iwlwifi driver and that I really dont have it.

Comment: @MartinMucha Try this: `sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms`. Reboot

Comment: Thanks. Did so and it turned out I didn't have installed headers for given kernel(and it was skipped in process), so I added them using: "sudo apt install linux-headers-5.19.0-45-generic", so I removed package you recommended again and reinstall it once again. Now I have it installed, 5.19.0-45-generic was processed during process. Rebooted, no wifi. Every command in update 1 and update behaves the same, only the dpkg one shows 'your' package.

Comment: Please `grep -ir iwl /etc/modprobe.d/` and `dkms status`.

Comment: @nobody please see update4. Thanks for your help, this is way over my skill. If the issue is somehow caused by conflict between new and old kernel, we can (well if you suggest how) remove iwlwifi, which is used by newer kernel as I won't be allowed to used it anyways, I need to make older one working and then stick with it (however problematic that might be).

Comment: The last from me `cat /proc/cmdline` please.

Comment: Thansk for your help, someone else had success with linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-45-generic so I tried if I have it as well, I didn't, and after installation of this one and reboot wifi works. Thanks for your help, I apologize if not knowing about this one was some rookie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize, I'm not that aware of these packages. What helped me was

```
sudo apt-get install linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-45-generic
```

I wasn't aware of this package. I didn't remove backport-iwlwifi-dkms mentioned in this thread, and it still works, so I will keep it I guess.